# Подтверждение post запроса на сайте

Tags: java, android

Пишу на java под android, отправляю пост запрос с данными, сервер говорит:

> JavaScript is currently disabled or is not supperted by your browser, Please click on the Submit button to continue.

Таким образом post-запрос не выполняется до конца, что делать с javascript? post запрос осуществляю через `httpurlconnection`, заранее спасибо

Comment: Если изначально было задумано, чтобы POST запросы на сервер отправлялись с какой-то веб страницы, а не как API для приложений, то возможно на сервере стоит проверка на отсутствие каких-то полей и/или передаваемых заголовков в POST запросе к серверу. Если есть возможность промониторить оригинальные POST запросы к серверу, которые успешно работают, посмотрите, возможно вы упустили какие-то данные или HTTP заголовки, на основе которых сервер делает заключение, что у вас нет поддержки JS.

Comment: нет с заголовками все в норме и данными тоже( я пишу личный кабинет моб. оператора и в стадии пополнения счета, я отправляю заключительные данные на сервер, сервер должен принять и отослать  на моб. телефон 3d код, поэтому там нужен javascript походу

Comment: не судьба походу

Comment: А пробовали подставлять заголовки User-Agent? Чтобы сервер думал, что запрос отправляется с браузера у которого точно есть поддержка JS?

Comment: Прописал, но это ничего не дало( по прежнему сервер возвращает код страницы, где написано, что javascript отключен и надо нажать кнопку продолжить, неужели нет выхода из этой ситуации...